# VBA MSXML2.XMLHTTP not getting Set-Cookie from response header

Tags: vba, api

I'm trying to retrieve Set-Cookie from response header I send using MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0.
But the response header doesn't include this type. Just standard ones like Agent, Server, Accept etc.
When I monitor network it is being sent.

I cannot use WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1 because it says 'No credentials were available in the client certificate' even if I sent one with the request.

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Maybe there are no cookies for this site? Can you use Wireshark to check the traffic?

Comment: No they are. As wrote, when using monitoring network traffic they are and when using python as well.